# SQL Join via an Association Number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables.  Shifts and Requests.

- A Shift can zero or many requests.
- A Shift is joined to a Request via a ShiftId
- A Shift MAY have an AssociationNumber.   So 2 shifts with the same AssociationNumber are connected.
- If a Shift has a Request and Additional shifts connected by AssociationNumber,  there will not be a Request for each of those Shifts.   So if there are 3 Shift records with different ShiftIds but the same association number there will only be one Request record linking to one of the ShiftIds.

I need to be able to return all Shifts by ShiftID with Requests if any, and all Associated Shifts IF there is a matching association number.

| ShiftId | AssociationNumber |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | null |

So for example  (ignoring the request join for brevity)
both the following queries should return the first 2 records.

Select * from Shifts
WHERE ShiftId = 1

Select * from Shifts
WHERE ShiftId = 2

```
CREATE TABLE Shifts  ([ShiftId] int, [AssociationNumber] int);
CREATE TABLE Requests  ([requestId] int, [shiftId] int);

INSERT INTO Shifts
    ([ShiftId], [AssociationNumber])
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 1),
    (3, 2),
    (4, 2),
    (5, null);


INSERT INTO Requests
    ([requestId], [shiftId])
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 3),
    (3, 5);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0e267f

Comment: So where does `requests` factor in to your example - how are you expecting results? This is not particularly clear.

Comment: The requests is probably the easiest parts I think.  The real issue is my point above about running 2 queries similar to below would return both the first and second records.  Because they have the same Association Id.   The problem being is I will only have 1 ShiftId as a parameter for the query.

Select * from Shifts WHERE ShiftId = 1
Select * from Shifts WHERE ShiftId = 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key here is you need a self join on shifts based on the association number.  This allows you to see all related shifts.  The key component is to filter on shifts from one table of the self join, and display the shifts from the other table.

The above concept is easier to visualize if you display S2.* below and remove the where clause.

```
SELECT S.*, R.*
FROM Shifts S
LEFT JOIN shifts s2
  on S.AssociationNumber = S2.AssociationNumber
LEFT JOIN Request R
  on S.ShiftID = R.ShiftID
WHERE S2.ShiftID = 1
```

Example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0e267f/7/0

Re-examine
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0e267f/11/0

Self Join Example unfiltered output.    `SELECT S.*, R.*, S2.*`

```
+---------+-------------------+-----------+---------+---------+-------------------+
| ShiftId | AssociationNumber | requestId | shiftId | ShiftId | AssociationNumber |
+---------+-------------------+-----------+---------+---------+-------------------+
|       1 | 1                 | 1         | 1       | 1       | 1                 |
|       1 | 1                 | 1         | 1       | 2       | 1                 |
|       2 | 1                 | (null)    | (null)  | 1       | 1                 |
|       2 | 1                 | (null)    | (null)  | 2       | 1                 |
|       3 | 2                 | 2         | 3       | 3       | 2                 |
|       3 | 2                 | 2         | 3       | 4       | 2                 |
|       4 | 2                 | (null)    | (null)  | 3       | 2                 |
|       4 | 2                 | (null)    | (null)  | 4       | 2                 |
|       5 | (null)            | 3         | 5       | (null)  | (null)            |
+---------+-------------------+-----------+---------+---------+-------------------+
```

Notice how the self join results in the multiplication of shifts from S and those in S2.  By filtering by the S2.shiftID, we get all shifts sharing the same association number.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty close but I will only have 1 ShiftId at a time.

So I won't be able to do this.
WHERE S2.ShiftID in (1,2)

Comment: @KevinRobinson  Take a look again, the IN was just me testing it worked for both, you can switch it to equal and set it up for 1 or 2 and it still returns both records.  So it doesn't matter if you use shiftID 1 or 2, both records are returned since association 1 ties both shifts together.